# How to retrieve information in a second thread with a Windows Forms C# Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, operating-system

I have an usual **C# Windows Forms Application with one Form and several TextBoxes / Labels** which runs (how I understand) in its own thread. (Win 7 64 / VS 2008 / Net 2).

Now I want to start a second thread while my base application stays in the first thread. 
The second thread shall retrieve some system information and input it into the Labels while my user is still able to fill in the TextBoxes while the information is going to be retrieved by the second thread. So the advantage would be by my understanding, that the user has not to wait until retrieving information is completed and the main application would not hang in that time.

Let's say I want this code to be executed in a second thread which starts in the Form_Shown event:

```
 Label1.Text = GetInternetIP();
 try
 {
 Label2.Text = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Label1.Text).HostName.ToString();
 }
 catch{MessageBox.Show("Fatal Error."); Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-r -t 2"); this.Activate(); SendKeys.Send("%{F4}");}
```

I would be grateful for a detailed description on how to setup a "new thread". I am a newbie but I would like to learn something new and optimize (speed up) my very first applications.

The Label1 and Label2 are in the main thread on the main form (Form1). So I have to get the retrieved information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three answers which I received brought me nowhere or have not worked, so I found it out myself much later: I used the Backgroundworker-Control to achieve what I wanted. In the "Completed"-Event of the Backgroundworker I can access the UI and transfer the information to the form attached to my application. What helps me a second thread if my UI is locked for that second thread, so Backgroundworker is the best for me to go and self-explaining.

Answer (score 0):

in dealing with Windows forms the UI can only run on one thread, then  it will create background threads the background threads retrieve the data and then pass it to the single UI Thread. This is also how it works in WPF.

take a look here on how to do this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300429.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should never access your UI components from code running on another thread.  In fact, you shouldn't access *anything* from multiple threads unless those things are explicitly thread-safe (or you access them in a thread-safe manner).

In your example you are saying you want to fetch information which takes some time.  In your case the programming model you want is to have your main thread call an asynchronous function to retrieve that information, and it should signal your main thread when the information is ready.

There are a lot of different ways to implement multithreaded programming in C#, but here is one example:

```
public Task<IPAddress> GetInternetIP()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        IPAddress ip;

        // do some work to get the IPAddress

        return ip;
    });
}

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetInternetIP().ContinueWith(ip =>
    {
        Label1.Text = ip.ToString();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

In this case what you're doing is executing a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` which will handle the multithreading for you.  And you're telling it to continue execution with a method on the current thread.  That method is passed the return value of the task (in this case an IPAddress object).

Answer (score 0):

to access user controls that are on the main thread from your background thread you only need to use BeginInvoke against the controls you want to populate.  This is an article that fully explains how to do so along with the ins and outs of doing so.

http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx